# jquery synchronous ajax only appends to html at end of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to run a php script multiple times but with a unique ID.
The script takes +- 5seconds to run each time ( downloads some files to server etc .. )
First i did this with an ajax call, but the problem was that this needs to be in sequential order, and with the default ajax settings multiple instances were run at the same time giving strange things.
I changed the parameter 'async' to 'false' which fixed the issue as now the javascript waits for the script to finish before starting the next iteration.

Console alerts pop up every 5-6 seconds and I alert back the data from each post and the loop waits for me to click the alert( good ).

**Instead of alerting i try to append the data to a div, it only appends after all iterations have been done.**

why?

```js
      var arr = ["10","20","30"];
       
        $("button").click(function(){
         $.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
         console.log( index + ": " + value );
         $.ajax({
              url: "import_xml_single_post.php",
              type: "post",
              data: {'import_id' : value},
              async: false,
              success: function(data){
               $( "#result" ).append( data );
             //alert(data);
           }     
          });
      });
```

```html
<body>
<button>Click me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is solely caused by `async: false`. It's bad practice to the point that the browser will actually show you a warning about its use. Instead, make the next AJAX call from the callback of the previous. Recursion is ideal for this. Better still, *don't make multiple calls' like this. It just needlessly floods the server. Amend the pattern your server side logic uses and send all data in a single request.

Comment: don't use a Synchronous ajax call, if you need to make sure an ajax only executes after someother ajax has ended you should store you callback and only call them after the somether ajax finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser's UI thread is hogged by the ajax requests, so the browser doesn't have a chance to repaint the page. That's one of the reasons why synchronous ajax is something to avoid using.

There's no need for those requests to be synchronous. If you want them done in series (not in parallel), just fire of a subsequent request when you finish the previous one:

```
var arr = ["10", "20", "30"];

$("button").click(function() {
    var index = 0;
    // Start the process
    doOne();
    function doOne() {
        // Get this value
        var value = arr[index++];
        console.log(index + ": " + value);
        $.ajax({
            url: "import_xml_single_post.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                'import_id': value
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#result").append(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
                // Kick off the next request
                if (index < arr.length) {
                    doOne();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In an cutting-edge environment (or with transpilation), you could use an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) so you could write synchronous-looking code that runs asynchronously:

```
var arr = ["10", "20", "30"];

$("button").click(async function() {
// ---------------^^^^^
    try {
        for (const value of arr) {
            console.log(value);
            await $.ajax({
    // -----^^^^^^
                url: "import_xml_single_post.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    'import_id': value
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#result").append(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle/report error doing request
    }
});
```

It's very important that you have a `try`/`catch` around the entire body of the function, because otherwise an error in the ajax call will not be handled (since nothing in jQuery is going to do anything with the promise the `async` function returns).

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm! should have thought about nesting the function like that .. 
Just for the record, adding some time after each request of my original code to allow the UI to update, would that work?

Comment: @DavidVerbeeck - Not if you stil had synchronous requests in a `for` loop in a normal function, no. There's no way to pause that and let the browser update its UI. But if you want to write synchronous-looking code that still runs asynchronously, you could use an `async` function; I've added an example and details to the answer.